# how to set the same expectation for an array of mock objects in trompeloeil?

Tags: c++, mocking, catch2, trompeloeil

I have an array of mocked objects and I need to provide the same expectation for many of them.
I can only succeed in this by manually writing the expectation for each object of the array.

**the function under test**

```
struct IWheel {
    virtual bool is_flat() = 0;
};

bool all_tyres_ok( IWheel* wheels[4] )
{
    return all_of(wheels, wheels+4, [](IWheel*w) { 
                      return w->is_flat(); 
                 });
}
```

**setting the expectations of the mocks**

```
struct MockWheel : public IWheel {
    MAKE_MOCK0(is_flat, bool(), override);
};

TEST_CASE("test_wheels")
{
    MockWheel w[4];
    {
        ALLOW_CALL(w[0], is_flat()).RETURN(true);
        ALLOW_CALL(w[1], is_flat()).RETURN(true);
        ALLOW_CALL(w[2], is_flat()).RETURN(false);
        ALLOW_CALL(w[3], is_flat()).RETURN(true);
        

        REQUIRE(all_tyres_ok(w) == false);
    }
}
```

Is there a way of setting the same expectation to many objects? and maybe override the expectation for some?
`for` loop does not work.

Comment: Why does a for loop  not work?